# How can I shift off a passed array reference directly to an array?

Tags: perl

I have a function (let's call it `foo($array_reference, ...)`) that expects an array reference among other parameters. I want to have `foo` shift the array reference off the list of parameters passed to it directly to an array, without having to shift it off as an array reference and then separately convert that to an array.

What I want should be something like:

```
my @bar = @{shift};
```

What I do not want, but am currently stuck with:

```
my $bar = shift;
my @bar = @{$bar}
```

The latter approach wastes lines, wastes memory, and causes me to hate the writer of this type of Perl code with a fiery passion. Help, please?

Comment: How do you figure it wastes memory?

Comment: Actually I'd, in the interest of writing readable code, wasted those few lines and wrote

    my $bar = shift; 
    my @bar = @$bar;

Experience tells me not to write perl golf, at least in production code.

Comment: @Ether: Wastes memory cause you have an extra variable ($bar) instantiated that you'll never need. 


@jira: it's ugly and less readable. You're creating extra variables you'll never need and splitting up tasks that should require just one line into two. I'm all for separating big complicated statements into multiple statements/lines, but this is something that should be done only when [i]necessary[/i]. Splitting up simple tasks into separate statements is wasteful, less readable, and should be avoided IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not worry about "wastes lines, wastes memory."  Both lines of code and memory are cheap.

You can operate on `@_` just like any array, and that includes dereferencing.  It sounds like you want one of:

```
my @bar = @{+shift};
my @bar = @{$_[0]};
```

Comment: The first one looks like it might be what I want. What's the "+" do?

Comment: @Eli: IIRC, forces scalar context.

Comment: @Eli, see "unary +" in perlop: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators

Comment: friedo's comment is much more accurate than Daenyth's

Answer (score 7):

Try `my @bar = @{shift()};` or `my @bar = @{CORE::shift()};`

Perl will warn you that `@{shift}` is ambigous if you enable warnings with `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 6):

Since its not here and I find it the clearest way to disambiguate:

```
my @bar = @{shift @_}
```

The reason that each of the answers here adds a non-word character inside the `@{ ... }` is because inside the brackets, `shift` is viewed as a unquoted bareword (similar to `abc => 1` or `$hash{key}`).  You can add `+`, `;`, `()`, `@_` or other non-word characters to force interpretation as code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
 my @bar = @{(shift)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to explicitly shift your arguments; `@_` contains direct aliases to them.

```
sub my_method
{
    my $this = shift;
    my @array = @{$_[0]};

}
```